# .NET TextBox - Handling the Enter Key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

What is definitively the best way of performing an action based on the user's input of the Enter key (`Keys.Enter`) in a .NET `TextBox`, assuming ownership of the key input that leads to suppression of the Enter key to the TextBox itself (e.Handled = true)?

Assume for the purposes of this question that the desired behavior is not to depress the default button of the form, but rather some other custom processing that should occur.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking what action to perform, or asking how to perform it, or asking how to be notified when the event occurs?

Comment: The definite best way is to do nothing.  The Enter key has a well defined meaning in UI design that shouldn't be tampered with.  Arbitrarily using it for focus changes in one form and the AcceptButton in another dialog just confuzzles the user to no end.

Comment: ChrisW: The basics are all really obvious. What I'm after here is how to deal with the caveats associated with the naive implementation, such as the fact that if you have data bound the Text property, then by the time you have handled, say, the KeyDown event the data source hasn't been updated with the value stored in the text box.

@Hans Passant: I hear you. In this case it's used in the context of a full text search box that is paired with optional (rarely used) other inputs. Pressing enter should perform the search.

Answer (score 84):

Add a keypress event and trap the enter key

Programmatically it looks kinda like this:

```
//add the handler to the textbox
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CheckEnterKeyPress);
```

Then Add a handler in code...

```
private void CheckEnterKeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)

        {
           // Then Do your Thang
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast here. Also this doesn't work properly when doing data binding on the textbox because the data source hasn't been updated at the point of the KeyDown and Keys.Return capture.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right about the redundant cast.  As to the issue with the data binding, can you add the keypress event after after the data binding has occurred?  Or you could use a try/catch to swallow the exception right?

Comment: The cast doesn't seem redundant now; it refuses to compile without.

Answer (score 27):

Inorder to link the function with the key press event of the textbox add the following code in the designer.cs of the form:

```
 this.textbox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.OnKeyDownHandler);
```

Now define the function 'OnKeyDownHandler' in the cs file of the same form:

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
       //enter key has been pressed
       // add your code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can drop this into the FormLoad event:

```
textBox1.KeyPress += (sndr, ev) => 
{
    if (ev.KeyChar.Equals((char)13))
    {
        // call your method for action on enter
        ev.Handled = true; // suppress default handling
    }
};
```

Comment: This won't suppress default handling.

Comment: All you need to add is `ev.Handled = true;` Updated post.

Comment: Not the best way to check for enter key either.

Comment: What would be the best way then?

Answer (score 3):

In cases you want some button to **handle Enter while program is executing**, just point the **AcceptButton** property of the form to the button.

E.g.: `this.AcceptButton = StartBtn;`

Comment: That assumes you have a button.

Answer (score 2):

Set the KeyPress event like this:

```
this.tMRPpart.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.tMRPpart_KeyPress);
```

Then you can perform actions including detecting the 'enter' key in the event -

```
private void tMRPpart_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // force any lower case characters into capitals
    if (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z')
        e.KeyChar -= (char)32;

    // If user presses return, tab to next tab stop
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        if (sender is Control)
        {
            // Move to next control
            SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I wanted the application to tab to the next field if the user pressed enter.