# C# dateTimePicker Focus does not work

Tags: c#, winforms

In my C# Windows Forms application I want to navigate between two `dateTimePicker` (`dateTimePicker1`, `dateTimePicker2`) by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
When the `Form` open focus on `dateTimePicker1` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then focus `dateTimePicker2` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key focus <kbd>dateTimePicker1</kbd>.

I'm trying the below code but it doesn't work:

```
private void dateTimePicker2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dateTimePicker1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: Is the code not executed or does it execute without setting your focus?

Comment: [`Enter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) is not an enter key press event. Use [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3558814/1997232).

Comment: Why Enter and not Tab, which would be more normal?

Comment: @mrali Did you solve the problem? If so then please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

The [Enter Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx) is triggered when you **enter** a control by *pressing tab to change focus or clicking into it*. If you want to listen for the **enter key** you need to use the [KeyDown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx).

An implementation of the event handling would look like this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        dateTimePicker2.Focus();
    }
}

private void dateTimePicker2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        dateTimePicker1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mrali Did my answer solve your problem or do you still have issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void dateTimePicker1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Focus();
    }
}

private void dateTimePicker2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine but when I am using the below code for all control of a Form your code does not work properly: private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }

Comment: @mrali Set `KeyPreview` of form to true

Answer (score 0):

The Enter event does not represent the key press of the Enter key, it represents the user changing focus to the control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use KeyDown event

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            dateTimePicker2.Focus();
    }
```