# How to make two textboxes working from both sides?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a simple **unit converter** in winforms, which means I'd be needing two `Textboxes`, in `textbox1` 'from' value is entered and in `textbox2` the converted value is printed out. I want to make it work the **other way around** too i.e. to take input from `textbox2` and to print the converted value out in `textbox1`. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: tried [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event yet?

Comment: @BagusTesa using a `TextChanged` event on both text boxes to modify the content of the other one will trigger recursively and indefinitely the events. You may need to detach the event before occuring the changes

Comment: @Cid you can unregister the event on TextBox2 while you are modifying at the beginning of TextBox1.TextChanged and re-register it at the end. Or use KeyPressed event

Comment: Perhaps the [leave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?) event is what you are looking for. Or you want to validate on enter key for non multiline text box https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558814/net-textbox-handling-the-enter-key

Comment: I would suggest to use the [Validated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validated?view=netframework-4.8) event, and update the other textbox when the first loses focus

Comment: For now write the conversion logic. The unit etc. Wrap it in a nice function with adequate parameter. In Visual studio, select one TB, in the property window on the right select the event bar. Double click in every event you want. Copy past the method call. Do the same for the other TB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement `TextChanged` event handlers for *both* `TextBox`es; the only difficulty is to understand which control (`textBox1` or `textBox2`)
has been changed by user (in order to prevent *infinite loop* when `textBox1`s value converts to `textBox2`s which in turn converts to `textBox1`s etc.). You can either check `Focused`:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Do nothing, if user is changing some other control (e.g. textBox2)
  if (!(sender as Control).Focused)
    return;

  // Having textBox1.Text value convert it forward to textBox2.Text
  textBox2.Text = Convert(textBox1.Text); 
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Do nothing, if user is changing some other control (e.g. textBox1)
  if (!(sender as Control).Focused)
    return;

  // Having textBox2.Text value convert it backward to textBox1.Text
  textBox1.Text = ReverseConvert(textBox2.Text); 
}
```

Or play with *event handlers* (which is more *flexible* esp. if you can start conversion, by, say, button click, so neither `textBox1` nor `textBox2` have focus):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox2.TextChange -= textBox2_TextChanged;

  try {
    // Since textBox2.TextChanged switched off,
    // changing textBox2.Text will not cause textBox1.Text change
    textBox2.Text = Convert(textBox1.Text); 
  }
  finally {
    textBox2.TextChange += textBox2_TextChanged;
  }
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox1.TextChange -= textBox1_TextChanged;

  try {
    // Since textBox1.TextChanged switched off,
    // changing textBox1.Text will not cause textBox2.Text change
    textBox1.Text = ReverseConvert(textBox2.Text); 
  }
  finally {
    textBox1.TextChange += textBox1_TextChanged;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle both textbox's Text change event in one Event handler (it will trigger event two times)

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Equals(textBox1)) 
        textBox2.Text = Convert((TextBox)sender).Text);
    else
        textBox1.Text = ReverseConvert((TextBox)sender).Text);
}
```

Comment: If I modify `textBox1.Text` then `textBox2.Text` will be changed which in turn cause `textBox1.Text` modification; if we have (*unit conversion*) *round errors* then `textBox1.Text` will be converted *once again* and we can well have an *infinte loop*

Comment: If the conversion is reversible, then there will be no issues.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei: It can be an issue if, say, `double` values are involved, e.g. `TextBox1: 18.0 -> TextBox2: 15.9999999999 -> TextBox1: 17.9999999999 -> TextBox2: 15.9999999998 -> TextBox1: 17.9999999996 -> ...`. It can stop, the loop is not necessary an *infinite* one, but values will be *ruined* (I want my initial `18.0`, not `17.99999994`)

Comment: I see, in this case it means it's not reversible, or as you mentioned, it suffers from rounding issues.